# Linux Mint 19.3 (x64) Host - VirtualBox 6.1 - No x64 Guests

Tags: linux, linux-mint, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have spent the last 2 days googling this issue and nothing seems to be working.

**Env:**
Linux Mint 19.3 updated fully
Virtualbox 6.1 (Installed using instructions here https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/linux-mint-how-tos/install-virtualbox-4-3-on-linux-mint-17.html)

Windows 8.1 on second HDD

**Problem:** 
I can run VirtualBox on Windows host just fine, I have enabled the bios options for Intel VT and all works fine. This rules out hardware. 
Using Linux Mint 19.3 as the host only gives me 32bit guest options. 
I've tried versions 5 and 6 of VirtualBox and neither one are happening on Linux.

I have uninstalled/purged each VB before trying to install the next one. I have downloaded the .deb file from the VB website and installed it through the package manager. And I have installed  using the info in the link I listed above. Neither work.

I'm out of ideas at this point so I'm turning to you guys.
Any help or advice you can give me is greatly appreciated, I just want this to work lol.